# Does a disowned process receive signals other than SIGHUP?

Tags: bash, shell, signals, disown

- Is it correct that a shell can send signals only to its jobs, but can't send signals to processes which are not its jobs?
- `disown` moves a job out of the job list of a shell. Does that mean a disowned process will not receive all the signals (not just SIGHUP) from its parent shell? If it will still receives other signals, why so?

Answer (score 3):

You can always send signals to any process you own. The shell presumably won't on it's own.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say I am only talking about signals sent from the parent shell. So the shell won't send any signal to a disowned process, not just SIGHUP?

Answer (score 1):

Easy to test:

`sleep` will die if it receives SIGUSR1:

```
$ sleep 999 &
[1] 7399
$ kill -USR1 7399
$
[1]+  User defined signal 1   sleep 999
```

So let's disown it and see if it survives:

```
$ sleep 999 &
[1] 7396
$ disown %1
$ jobs
$ ps -fp 7396
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
schaller  7396  7360  0 19:59 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 999
$ kill -USR1 7396
$ ps -fp 7396
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
$
```